# SoundManager 2 All Loading Finished?

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

If I create a bunch of sounds in my `soundmananger.onready` function which all inherit the `autoLoad: true` from `soundmanager.defaultOptions`. Is there an easy way to detect when all of these sounds have been successfully loaded instead of having a `onload` function for each sound?

Answer (score 0):

Fully loaded or loaded enough to play?

If you are using flash for audio playback onload will fire when all bytes of a song have been loaded.

If you are using HTML5 audio then onload will fire when enough of the song has been loaded to start playing.

I don't believe there is a bulk way to check all sounds.